# Regex in std c++

Tags: c++, regex

I want to find all occurences of something like this '{some text}'.

My code is:

```
std::wregex e(L"(\\{([a-z]+)\\})");
    std::wsmatch m;


    std::regex_search(chatMessage, m, e);
    std::wcout << "matches for '" << chatMessage << "'\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.size(); ++i) {
        std::wssub_match sub_match = m[i];
        std::wstring sub_match_str = sub_match.str();
        std::wcout << i << ": " << sub_match_str << '\n';
    }
```

but for string like this: L"Roses {aaa} {bbb} are {ccc}  #ff0000") my output is:

```
0: {aaa}
1: {aaa}
2: aaa
```

and I dont get next substrings. I suspect that there is something wrong with my regular expression. Do anyone of you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're searching once and simply looping through the groups. You instead need to search multiple times and return the correct group only. Try:

```
std::wregex e(L"(\\{([a-z]+)\\})");
std::wsmatch m;

std::wcout << "matches for '" << chatMessage << "'\n";
while (std::regex_search(chatMessage, m, e))
{
    std::wssub_match sub_match = m[2];
    std::wstring sub_match_str = sub_match.str();
    std::wcout << sub_match_str << '\n';
    chatMessage = m.suffix().str(); // this advances the position in the string
}
```

`2` here is the second group, i.e. the second thing in brackets, i.e. `([a-z]+)`.

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more on groups.

Comment: I try your code but this result with infinite loop what print 'aaa' string.

Comment: This one help. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the regular expression, but you need to search for it repeatedly. And than you don't really need the parenthesis anyway.

The `std::regex_search` finds *one* occurence of the pattern. That's the `{aaa}`. The `std::wsmatch` is just that. It has 3 submatches. The whole string, the content of the outer parenthesis (which is the whole string again) and the content of the inner parenthesis. That's what you are seeing.

You have to call `regex_search` again on the rest of the string to get the next match:

```
std::wstring::const_iterator begin = chatMessage.begin(), end = chatMessage.end();
while (std::regex_search(begin, end, m, e)) {
    // ...
    begin = m.end();
}
```

Comment: When I invoke regex_search again I get string 'aaa' again. Is there any other way?

Comment: Well, you can call `regex_search` with a range. So just pass end of the previous match as start of the range.

Comment: This not working :( I have compiler error in line begin = m.end();. Thete is no operator "=" matches this operands.

Comment: @AYMADA: `std::wsmatch` should be `std::match_results<std::wstring::const_iterator>`, so it's `begin()` and `end()` should return `std::wstring::const_iterator`. Can you quote the error message including _what_ operands it has (all compilers print that)?

Answer (score 1):

The index operator on a `regex_match` object returns the matching substring at that index. When the index is 0 it returns the entire matching string, which is why the first line of output is `{aaa}`. When the index is 1 it returns the contents of the first capture group, that is, the text matched by the part of the regular expression that is between the first `(` and the corresponding `)`. In this example, those are the outermost parentheses, which once again produces `{abc}`. When the index is 2 is returns the contents of the second capture group, i.e., the text between the second `(` and its corresponding `)`, which gives you the `aaa`.

The easiest way to search again from where you left off is to use an iterator:

```
std::wsregex_iterator it(chatMessage.begin(), chatMessage.end(), e);
for ( ; it != wsregex_iterator(); ++it) {
    std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

(note: this is a sketch, not tested)